# Drupal Multi-Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am having trouble creating a multi-join mysql query in drupal. Here's my code:

```
if ($params['mobile_app']) {
  if (isset($params['mobile_app_date'])) {
    $query->join('field_data_field_on_mobile_app', 'm', 'm.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query->join('field_data_field_mobile_app_date', 'm', 'm.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query
      ->condition('m.field_on_mobile_app_value', 1)
      ->condition('m.field_mobile_app_date_value', dosomething_helpers_convert_date($params['mobile_app_date']), '<=')
      ->condition('m.field_mobile_app_date_value2', dosomething_helpers_convert_date($params['mobile_app_date']), '>=');
  } else {
    $query->join('field_data_field_on_mobile_app', 'm', 'm.entity_id = n.nid');
    $query->condition('m.field_on_mobile_app_value', 1);
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'm.field_mobile_app_date_value' in 'where clause'"
```

It's interesting though because when separated, the queries work fine. It's just when I try to combine them, it breaks. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Separate queries (works):

- ?mobile_app=1
- ?mobile_app_date=2015-10-01

Combined (doesn't work):

- ?mobile_app=1&mobile_app_date=2015-10-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out! I just changed 'm' to 'mad' in the second query so they weren't the same.

Comment: yes, table alias name has issue, you can not assign same alias name to two different tables. Anyways, congrats you figured it out well by your own. hope your trouble comes to an end.

Comment: Thanks @sourdrup2012!